# Group visa applied but not received for one member

Tags: uk, vfs-global

Our family (5 adults) applied for UK tourist visas. We applied together. On 26-04-2019, 4 of us received the visas, but one of my sister’s visa has not arrived yet.

We have our trip on 9-05-2019 and our Schengen visa is also pending. We had applied in PV so it should come within a week.
Is there any contact number that I can call and ask if our daughter’s application has been assessed?

I tried to call the following numbers: 00448435047198/00443001232241 but there was no option for me to ask about our situation. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: You mention a sister and a daughter, are you talking about one visa here or two?